# Running Grails Project on Glassfish v 2.1 on STS

Tags: grails, glassfish, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS to develop my Grails project. I want to deploy it on Glassfish v 2.1. I have set up Glassfish AS on STS on the Servers View. But I cannot do a Run on Server on the Grails Project to deploy it on Glassfish Server. I can do a grails run-app on the embedded tomcat, but I want it to deploy on Glassfish.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: I also tried setting the Targetted Runtimes. But when I add the glassfish app server, it is not highlighted. only vmFabric server is highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a [reply on STS forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113865-Running-a-Grails-Project-on-Glassfish-v-2.1-on-STS) that it doesn't support Glassfish.